# lastclick var not getting set correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have this piece of javascript for sorting html elements.

```
SortingElements = function () {

    var $this = $(this);

    var order = "desc";
    var lastClicked = null;
    var list = null;
    var sorting = null;

    var init = function() {

        var prevClicked = lastClicked;

        sorting = $this.attr("data-sort");

        if (prevClicked == sorting)
            order = (order == "desc") ? "asc" : "desc";

        lastClicked = sorting;

        list = $('.sorting-list'), lis = $('.sort-item'), liHeight = lis[0].offsetHeight;

        $(list).css('height', list.outerHeight());

        tinysort('.sorting-list .sort-item', { selector: 'span[data-sorting="' + sorting + '"]', order: order }).forEach(function (elm, i) {

            $(elm).fadeOut(i * 175);
            $(elm).fadeIn(i * 175);

        });
    }

    init();

}
```

This scripts is called with `$('.sort-selector-item').click(SortingElements);` that is an anchor list to sort f.x. by name, company, etc.

```
<ul class="no-list list-inline list-unstyled sort-selector margin-bottom-30">
    <li><a href="#" class="sort-selector-item" data-sort="name">Navn</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="sort-selector-item" data-sort="company">Virksomhed</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="sort-selector-item" data-sort="position">Stilling</a></li>
</ul>
```

My problem is the prevClicked variable. It is supposed to get the value of the previous clicked item so that it can sort sort both ascending and descending if I click the same item again without clicking another, that is if I click on "name" it will sort descending, and if I click on "name" again it will sort ascending.

In short if it contains the same value as the sorting var it should sort ascending / descending

But the problem is that it is always `null`, might be because of `var prevClicked = lastClicked;`

Comment: A simpler solution would be just to add a blank class like last-clicked at the beginning of the script then check `if $(this).hasClass('last-clicked')` bla bla then add the class again at the end of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `lastClicked` and `order` don't persist between function calls.
Making them closures (which was likely your intention with `init`) should help:

```
SortingElements = (function()
{
    var order = "desc";
    var lastClicked = null;
    return function() // This function "becomes" SortingElements
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        var list = null;
        var sorting = null;
        var prevClicked = lastClicked;

        sorting = $this.attr("data-sort");
        if (prevClicked == sorting)
            order = (order == "desc") ? "asc" : "desc";
        lastClicked = sorting;
        list = $('.sorting-list'), lis = $('.sort-item'), liHeight = lis[0].offsetHeight;
        $(list).css('height', list.outerHeight());
        tinysort('.sorting-list .sort-item',
        {
            selector: 'span[data-sorting="' + sorting + '"]',
            order: order
        }).forEach(function (elm, i)
        {
            $(elm).fadeOut(i * 175);
            $(elm).fadeIn(i * 175);

        });
    };
})();
```